# Annotation with parameter using annox

Tags: parameters, constructor, xjc, annox

I am searching for a way to use "annox" to annotate a generated class. The goal is to add a hibernate annotation to the generated class, that has a constructor value. Here is an example of the desired result:

```
public class XJCGeneratedClass {

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
Sample sample;
...
}
```

You see: I have a constructor parameter given to the annotation.

I already have the Part of the @Enumeration working in the correspdonding xsd:

```
<xs:element name="sample">
<xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
        <annox:annotate>
                <hs:Enumerated impl="javax.persistence.Enumerated" >
                <!-- WHAT ELSE DO IT NEED TO MAKE ANNOX PRODUCE "@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)" FOR THIS FIELD? -->
            </hs:Enumerated>
            </annox:annotate>
    </xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
```

Of course, when I generate my sources an error is yielded because the Annotation does not exist without a Parameter. Thrown error is:

> Could not parse the value [     ] into the target class [javax.persistence.EnumType]

I tried a lot (for example including value-Tag), but I cannot add the correct behaviour to add the Enumerated-Annotation with the EnumType.STRING as a parameter.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried:

```
<hs:Enumerated value="STRING"/>
```

See the [user guide](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/ANX/User+guide).